# How can I create aar file in android studio 0.1 Build 130.677228

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the older version of the android studio that when I launch it, in the bottom of the wizard window is written such a thing:

```
android studio 0.1 Build 130.677228, check for update now
```

I updated android studio to newer version, But it can not run in my computer. But fortunately, the older version of the android studio runs in my computer well and the older version of the android studio is enough for me.

Consider I created a new project in android studio(The same default project), and I want create `aar` file form my project. Most of you use like me used the older version of the android studio before using the newer version.
How can I create `aar` file in android studio 0.1 Build 130.677228?

Comment: did it helped you? When so, upvote and check my answer pls.

Answer (score 0):

I had hold a talk about creating and using aar in pre Android Studio 1.x.

You can view the slides here:
http://de.slideshare.net/RenMertins/get-startedwithaar-pdfexportrem20141012

How does it work in short:

1. Create a project with one library module
2. call gradle asemble release
3. go in the build folder and copy out the aar file

To use your aar in your own projects, create a local maven repository, copy in your aar and reference it over gradle in other android app project.

All described in my talk. Have fun